# Multi platform android apps

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-tv

I have developed an android application which works on both smartphone and tablet plateforms. 
How can I make this application works on android TV and android mini pc?!
Do I need to change the layouts or I have to develop an independent application for each plateform?

Comment: for android tv you need to create independent app because its structure is different.

Comment: thanks. What about android mini pc ?

Comment: you mean android mini pc connected with android os set top box or something like that ?

Comment: Yes especially those connected to tv via hdmi.

Comment: for that whatever app you have created just installed that apk in that device and it will work.

Comment: i have added my answer please accept if this information helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For android tv application you need to create independent app because it is using leanback library structure.

And same tv app will work with android Mini PC but remember the device which you are using is minimum with Api Level 21 because the tv apps are only run above api level 21.

I hope this information will help you to develop your tv application.

Comment: please upvote it also.

Comment: @Rockers23 you are welcome. please upvote it also if it is helpful to you.

Comment: I can't vote yet. thx :)